# Error found when loading /home/[myusername]/.profile

Tags: .profile

I get this error each time after logging on:

```
Error found when loading /home/[myusername]/.profile:

stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

As a result the session will not be configured correctly. You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.

How do I fix this? This is an annoying popup to have to click on each logon (and this error also prevents my desktop background changes from persisting). Thank you!

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Comment: Open Nautilus and open the `Home` folder. Press `ctrl`+`H` and rename `.profile` to `.profile1`. Reboot and see if that helps.

Comment: What happens when you do `source ~/.profile` from terminal? BTW the user is you, right? I mean its the problematic user's `~/.profile`?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: This is likely due to `~/.bashrc` having some `stty` command.